# Boolean result from checking an objects enum

Tags: java, enums, boolean

I am working on a program that uses the Shunting-Yard algorithm.

I am having trouble checking if the token is of a number, operator, right brace and left brace. I have an enum in the token class that is being set correctly, however how can I return a boolean checking if it is of a type?

From token class:

```
enum TokenType {
    Nothing, Number, Operator, LeftBrace, RightBrace
};
```

Code giving me problems, if the enum is set to number I want it to return true for the first test and false for the second.

```
if (inputTokenized[index].getTokenType().Number) {
    //...
} else if(inputTokenized[index].getTokenType().LeftBrace) {
    //...
}
```

Looks like I figured it out.

```
if (inputTokenized[index].getTokenType().Number == Token.TokenType.Number) {
    //...
} else if(inputTokenized[index].getTokenType().LeftBrace == Token.TokenType.LeftBrace) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: You have to compare it to something.

Comment: Looks like like you have answered it yourself. Either close the question or post your solution as a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (inputTokenized[index].getTokenType().Number == Token.TokenType.Number) {

    } else if(inputTokenized[index].getTokenType().LeftBrace == Token.TokenType.LeftBrace) {

    }
```

Comment: I don't know what the rest of your code does, but it seems like it should be: inputTokenized[index].getTokenType() == Token.TokenType.Number

Answer (score 0):

You can keep all of the logic inside the enum class:

```
public enum TokenType {
    NOTHING, NUMBER, OPERATOR, LEFT_BRACE, RIGHT_BRACE;

    public static TokenType getType(char c){
        if(Character.isDigit(c))
            return NUMBER;
        // ... implement other types
        else
            return NOTHING;
    }
}
```

Then you can check if a certain character is of a certain type

```
TokenType.getType('5') == TokenType.NUMBER           // true
TokenType.getType('5') == TokenType.LEFT_BRACE       // false
```